# How does local and global error relate for finite difference methods?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

When solving a (one-dimensional linear) boundary value problem by finite differences, how does the local and global error relate? I would have expected that if the local error was $O(h^k)$ in the step size $h$ then the global error would be $O(h^{k-1})$, as with integration of initial value problems (with the usual Lipschitz continuity condition). But when reading an example in Sauer's Numerical Analysis (section 7.2.1) where the second order central difference approximation
$$ 
u''(x) = \frac{u(x - h) - 2 u(x) + u(x + h)}{h^2} + O(h^2)
$$
is used, he seems to imply that the global error is $O(h^2)$ as well. Is that right, and if so why?

Possible follow-up: How does this generalize to partial differential equations?

Comment: This type of BVP is of the form $Au=f$, where $A$ is something with error $O(h^2)$. IVPs require repeated, iterative applications of something with error, say $O(h^2)$. This iterative procedure is where the reduction in order for IVPs comes from, whereas solving BVPs is a "one-shot" process in a sense. The error estimates that show this are not trivial, but they differ from IVPs for this reason.

Comment: I see. That might explain why Sauer did not go any deeper into why the global error was $O(h^2)$; it is just an introductory book so perhaps the error analysis for BVPs is a bit too advanced. I'm looking now at Ames' Numerical Methods for Partial Differential Equations, which seems to have some of what I am looking for.